# .net - Minify Your Dto In Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, .net-6.0

Imagine if you have a dto that includes many properties that are applicable to the business logic. A simple example would be the following:

```
public class PartnerDto
    {
        public int PartnerId { get; set; }
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public int CobrandIdId { get; set; }
        public Brand brand { get; set; }
    }
```

In this example the `Brand` class onto itself has custom properties.

This is great, except when I like the WebApi to consume this class either in the response body, or as a request payload. But what if the client doesn't care about the custom properties? Let's say the client only cares about the `int` fields in this case.

One idea was to create a `MiniPartnerDto` that only includes the properties I like to expose to the client. Then, use `AutoMapper` to map the two objects. Essentially the following:

```
public class MiniPartnerDto
    {
        public int PartnerId { get; set; }
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public int CobrandIdId { get; set; }
    }

[HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
        {
            var result = _mapper.Map<MiniPartnerDto>(await _partnerManager.GetById(id));
            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

I don't mind this idea, but I don't love it. I was wondering if there is a way for me to ignore certain properties without having the need to create a completely different class.

Comment: Having separate view models for different requirements is a good practice and the other methods are too painful (like custom model binding). Also you can use inheritince if you don't want to type properties multiple times

Comment: I was thinking the same. I could use the `MiniPartnerDto` as base and inherit it in the the `PartnerDto` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make more object values ,one of the ways is [conditional property serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm) in `Json.NET`.

Try it like this:

```
public class PartnerDto
{
    public int PartnerId { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public int CobrandIdId { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeBrand()
    {
        // Brand property serialized only when brand name is Stackoverflow
        return (Brand.Name == "Stackoverflow");
    }
}
```

In Complex cases you can handle it by enum like this:

```
public enum SLForPartnerDto
{
    None,
    ViewForm,
    EditForm
}

public class PartnerDto
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public SLForPartnerDto SerializationLevel { get; set; }
    public int PartnerId { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public int CobrandIdId { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializePartnerId()
    {
        return (SerializationLevel != SLForPartnerDto.None);
    }
    public bool ShouldSerializeBrand()
    {
        return (SerializationLevel == SLForPartnerDto.ViewForm);
    }
}
```

Now you need just set `SerializationLevel` in model like:

```
var model = new PartnerDto();
model.SerializationLevel = SLForPartnerDto.ViewForm;
```

But I think it is not best practice.